# Comenzar de nuevo una transición o animación en css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

quisiera saber si : Hay alguna forma de reiniciar la animación de una transición en css? me explico: al momento de dar click varias veces a una imagen en una galería vaya de saturacion 0% a 100%, y que no vaya de 100% a 0%.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>

      body{
        text-align: center;
        background-color: black;
      }

      img{
        border: solid white 2px;
      }

      .saturada{
        filter: saturate(0%)
      }

      .normal{
        transition: 4s;
        filter: saturate(100%)
      }
      
      .main img{
        width: 700px;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .second img{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        filter: saturate(0%)
      }
      
    </style>
    <title>Ejercicio Nro. 2</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="main"><img src="assets/img/coronas.jpg" alt="" class="grande saturada"></div>
      <div class="second">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" alt="" class="chica">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1" alt="" class="chica">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2" alt="" class="chica">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3" alt="" class="chica">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4" alt=""   class="chica">
      </div>

    <script>
      $(".chica").on("click", function(){
        ruta = $(this).attr("src");
        $(".grande").attr("src", ruta);
        $(".grande").toggleClass("normal")
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Esto es lo que tengo.

Answer (score 5):

Un tanto engañoso el efecto por la pereza (optimización) de los navegadores al dibujar cosas y manejar el quitar y poner clases rápidamente.

Normalmente cuando hay un evento y se quiere que la animación sea de una sola vía, se "resetea" el tiempo de transición, por ejemplo:

```css
input {
  transition: 1s;
  background: #fff;
}

input:focus {
  transition: 0s;
  background: #fe0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="click para hacer focus"><br/>
<input type="text" value="click para hacer focus"><br/>
<input type="text" value="click para hacer focus"><br/>
<input type="text" value="click para hacer focus"><br/>
<input type="text" value="click para hacer focus"><br/>
<input type="text" value="click para hacer focus"><br/>
```

En el caso planteado, manejarlo con clases tiene efectos variados en distintos navegadores, pero por lo general son bastante "lazy" y no logran el efecto deseado. Los posibles eventos para colgarse son cuando cambia el `src` de la imagen o cuando termina de cargarse (`on load`) en ambos casos las propiedades css parecieran ir por otro lado y se computa el final.

Así que echando mano del `jQuery.animate` usamos una propiedad css ficticia "x" la ponemos a `0` al cambiar el `src` (esto no cambia la imagen, así que el optimizador no hace nada) luego animamos esta propiedad "x" hasta 100 y en cada paso actualizamos el css del `filter`, el `queue:false` evita que se encolen los animates asi a cada click parte de `0` y va hasta `100`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    img {
      border: solid white 2px;
    }
    
    .saturada {
      transition: 0s;
      filter: saturate(0%);
    }
    
    .main img {
      width: 580px;
      height: 300px;
    }
    
    .second img {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      filter: saturate(0%)
    }
  </style>
  <title>Ejercicio Nro. 2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="second">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" alt="" class="chica">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1" alt="" class="chica">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2" alt="" class="chica">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3" alt="" class="chica">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4" alt="" class="chica">
  </div>
  <div class="main"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" alt="" class="grande saturada"></div>

  <script>
    $(".chica").on("click", function() {
          ruta = $(this).attr("src");


          $(".grande").attr("src", ruta);
          $(".grande").css("x", "0");
          $(".grande").animate(
              {x: 100}, 
              {
              queue: false,
              duration: 1000,
              step: function(now) {$(".grande").css("filter", "saturate(" + now + "%)");}
              })
          })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**nota:** cambié los tamaños y el orden para que se note el efecto sin tener que ir a "pagina completa"

Answer (score 3):

Al hacer `toggleClass`, lo que vas a hacer es poner o quitar la clase. Eso va a hacer que la animación que quieras sólo se vea una de cada dos veces (la vez que se añade la clase). Una cosa que puedes hacer es al principio quitar la clase con `removeClass` y al final del método añadir la clase de nuevo con `addClass`.

Pero eso va a dar problemas por cómo funcionan los navegadores a la hora de hacer animaciones y el tiempo de refresco. Una solución simple sería añadir un pequeño retardo de al menos 16ms al añadido de la clase (los 16ms pueden parecer un *número mágico*, pero tienen su explicación en los frames por segundo/fps en los que corre normalmente una animación en un monitor a 60Hz, como se explica [aquí](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/rendering/) y [aquí](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/) en inglés). Ese retraso es inapreciable para una persona viendo la animación, pero es suficiente para forzar al navegador a realizarla completa como quieres.

Aquí puedes ver el código funcionando con esos cambios:

```js
$(".chica").on("click", function() {
  $(".grande").removeClass("normal");
  ruta = $(this).attr("src");
  $(".grande").attr("src", ruta);
  setTimeout('$(".grande").addClass("normal")', 16);
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  border: solid white 2px;
}

.saturada {
  filter: saturate(0%)
}

.normal {
  transition: 4s;
  filter: saturate(100%)
}

.main img {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
}

.second img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  filter: saturate(0%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="main"><img src="assets/img/coronas.jpg" alt="" class="grande saturada"></div>
<div class="second">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=0" alt="" class="chica">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=1" alt="" class="chica">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=2" alt="" class="chica">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=3" alt="" class="chica">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?image=4" alt="" class="chica">
</div>
```